# How to italicize just gene names in my heatmap (using R)?

Tags: r, heatmap, italic

I am doing a heatmap in R (gplots) and I would like to italicize just my gene names (in my example - gene1, gene2 and gene3).
For example:

```
df <- data.frame(Gene = c ("gene1", "gene2",  "gene3"), value = c(3, 2, 2.5), time = c("10d","10d","10d"))
gplots::heatmap.2(cbind(df$value, df$value), trace= "none", Colv = NA, labCol = "", labRow = df$Gene, Rowv=FALSE)
```

I tried (did not work):

```
df <- data.frame(Gene = c ( expression(italic("gene1", "gene2",  "gene3"))), value = c(3, 2, 2.5), time = c("10d","10d","10d"))
```

or

```
df <- data.frame(Gene = expression(italic(c ("gene1", "gene2",  "gene3"))), value = c(3, 2, 2.5), time = c("10d","10d","10d"))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it progammatically:

```
gene_list <- as.character(df$Gene)

make_italics <- function(x) {
  as.expression(lapply(x, function(y) bquote(italic(.(y)))))
}

heatmap.2(
  cbind(df$value, df$value),
  trace = "none",
  Colv = NA,
  labCol = "",
  labRow = make_italics(gene_list),
  Rowv = FALSE
)
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, but I have 30 genes, so it is time consuming to include one by one ...

Comment: @Alex - I've edited the answer to make it work without needing to type all the gene names manually